# How can I use Distinct with Order by SubString in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How can I use Distinct with Order by SubString in SQL?

My query is

```
  SELECT 
 Distinct [Units Period]   
 FROM Table_Name
ORDER BY RIGHT([Units Period], 4) DESC , SUBSTRING([Units Period], 5, 2) DESC
```

But it didnt work.

Comment: Didn't work does not tell us anything. Share the details if you want to get any help please.

Comment: Sample data, expected results would be useful things to include in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The error is: `ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.`

so rewrite query with `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT 
  [Units Period]   
FROM 
  Table_Name
GROUP BY
  [Units Period]   
ORDER BY 
  RIGHT([Units Period], 4) DESC , 
  SUBSTRING([Units Period], 5, 2) DESC
```

or add all the columns after distinct:

```
SELECT 
  distinct
  [Units Period],
  RIGHT([Units Period], 4), 
  SUBSTRING([Units Period], 5, 2)
FROM 
  Table_Name
ORDER BY 
  RIGHT([Units Period], 4) DESC , 
  SUBSTRING([Units Period], 5, 2) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can re-write the query as:

```
 Select [Units Period] 
 From (
       SELECT 
       Distinct [Units Period]   
       FROM Table_Name) T
ORDER BY RIGHT([Units Period], 4) DESC , SUBSTRING([Units Period], 5, 2) DESC
```